# Is there a way to simplify this pygame code?

Tags: python, pygame, simplify

I am a bit new to pygame, and I don't know if there was a way to simplify this and it would also be nice if you could change colors while drawing. I already tried to implement this but I couldn't find a way to let it work. It's basically a simple pixel-art game:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit


def MousePos():
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    return mouse_pos[0] // grid_size, mouse_pos[1] // grid_size


def DrawGrid():
    for x in range(0, WIDTH, grid_size):
        for y in range(0, HEIGHT, grid_size):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, grid_size, grid_size)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, "Black", rect, 1)


def DrawSquare():
    mouse_buttons = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if mouse_buttons[0] and MousePos() not in pressed:
        pressed.append(MousePos())
    if mouse_buttons[1] and MousePos() not in pressed:
        pressed.clear()
    if mouse_buttons[2] and MousePos() in pressed:
        pressed.remove(MousePos())
    for coordinates in pressed:
        rectangle = pygame.Rect(coordinates[0]*grid_size, coordinates[1]*grid_size, grid_size, grid_size)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, "Black", rectangle)
    cursor = pygame.Rect(MousePos()[0]*grid_size, MousePos()[1]*grid_size, grid_size, grid_size)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, "Grey", cursor)


pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("PixelArt!")

grid_size = 25
pressed = []
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    screen.fill("White")

    MousePos()
    DrawGrid()
    DrawSquare()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: there is good rule: `lowe_case_names` for functions - i.e. `mouse_pos()`, `draw_grid()`, `draw_quare()`. See more: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I don't know what is the problem to change colors while drawing. You have to keep color in variable and use some `if/else` to decide how to change color. Or you can use `randome.choice(lost_of_colors)` to get random color. Or you can check mouse position and if you clicked in top left square then change color in variable, etc.

Comment: in `DrawSquare()` you run `MousePos()` many times but you could run it only once and assign result to variable - `pos = MousePos()` - and later use this variable

Comment: btw: maybe this question should go on similar portal [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Maybe this question should go on similar portal [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

---

[image]

I keep drawing color in variable and use keys to change it.

`1 = Red`, `2 = Green`, `3 = Blue`, `0 = Black`

But now it needs to keep `color` with `pos` - and I use dictionary `pressed[pos] = color`

But maybe instead of `pressed` you should create full list 2D for all squares in grid and put `White` in all places at start. If you would colors as tuples i.e. `(255,0,0)` instead string `Red` then you could keep it in `numpy.array` and simply save in text file or convert `numpy.array` to `Pillow.Image` and save as JPG/PNG/TIFF.

Because now it can draw in different colors so I don't check if `pos not in pressed` when I press first button because it not allow to replace color in square.

---

There is not so much to simplify.

In `DrawSquare()` you run `MousePos()` many times but you could run it once and assign to variable.

You can use `x, y = ...` instead of `pos = ...` and `pos[0]`, `pos[1]`.
Or you can use both `x, y = pos = ...`.

You can create `cursor = Rect(...)` at start and later use `cursor.topleft = new_position` to move it.

Maybe in `draw.rect(...)` you could use directly tuples `(x, y, width, height)` instead of `Rect(x, y, width, height)`

---

I used rules from [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

- `lower_case_names` for functions names
- `verbs` for functions names - `convert` instead of `MousePos`
  (and `nouns` for variables and classes)

---

Full code:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

# --- constants ---  # PEP8: `UPPER_CASE_NAMES`

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 400

SQUARE_SIZE = 25

# --- classes ---   # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames`

# empty

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` 

def convert_pos(pos):
    x, y = pos
    return (x // SQUARE_SIZE, y // SQUARE_SIZE)

def draw_grid():
    for x in range(0, WIDTH, SQUARE_SIZE):
        for y in range(0, HEIGHT, SQUARE_SIZE):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, "Black", rect, 1)

def draw_square():
    mouse_buttons = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    
    grid_x, grid_y = grid_pos = convert_pos(mouse_pos)

    cursor.topleft = (grid_x*SQUARE_SIZE, grid_y*SQUARE_SIZE)
    
    if mouse_buttons[0]:
        pressed[grid_pos] = draw_color
        
    if mouse_buttons[1]: # and grid_pos not in pressed:
        pressed.clear()
        
    if mouse_buttons[2] and grid_pos in pressed:
        #del pressed[grid_pos]
        pressed.pop(grid_pos)

    for (x, y), color in pressed.items():
        rectangle = pygame.Rect(x*SQUARE_SIZE, y*SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rectangle)
    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, "Grey", cursor)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()
                         
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("PixelArt!")

pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

pressed = {}  # dictionary for `pressed[position] = color

cursor = pygame.Rect(0, 0, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE)

draw_color = 'Black'

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                draw_color = 'Red'         
            elif event.key == pygame.K_2:
                draw_color = 'Green'         
            elif event.key == pygame.K_3:
                draw_color = 'Blue'         
            elif event.key == pygame.K_0:
                draw_color = 'Black'         

    # - draw -
 
    screen.fill("White")

    draw_grid()
    draw_square()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```